# Blur(unfocus) an element when other element is clicked

Tags: javascript, blur

```
document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
var filter = document.getElementById('filter');
  if (e.target !== filter[0]) {
    filter.blur();
  }
});
```

My attempt ^^

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) { 
  if (e.target !== $('#filter')[0]) 
  $('#filter').blur();
});
```

When any element except #filter is clicked I would like to blur (unfocus) #filter

Comment: And, what is your question?

Comment: Please formulate a question in the title.

Comment: This wasn't working and I was wondering how to make it work..

Comment: He's obviously trying to convert the jQuery code to Javascript. Read the title.

Comment: Did you do any basic debugging to find out what was happening in your event handler (whether it was getting called, whether the `if` condition was getting satisfied and if not, why not)?

Comment: @jfriend00, your changes were un-done by ejay_francisco...Did you see that?

Comment: OK, didn't realize it was someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to dereference the result of `getElementById` with the `[0]` - the result is already a single element.

The `[0]` is only necessary in jQuery because jQuery results are always pseudo-arrays even if there's only one matching element.

Given this function is being called for every single click on the page, consider moving the definition of `filter` outside of the function so that you don't have to re-evaluate it for every click (assuming that the element is static).